# NextJs: attempted to hard navigate to the same URL error while passing query string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, next.js, query-string

I'm working on NextJs version `13.0.2` and ReactJs version `18.2.0`. I want to pass a query string in the URL but I get:

```
Error: Invariant: attempted to hard navigate to the same URL /@workamirdanesh?w=true http://localhost:3000/@workamirdanesh?w=true
```

Everything is ok when I go to the `http://localhost:3000/@workamirdanesh` URL. But when I add a query string like: `?w=true` and it becomes: `http://localhost:3000/@workamirdanesh?w=true`, I get the above error.

How can I solve it and what is the problem here? obviously, the query string should not throw an error and should load the page with the URL before the query string.

UPDATE: I updated the NextJs version to `13.0.7` and the problem still exists.

Answer (score 6):

Got the same issue

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Invariant: attempted to hard navigate to the same URL /listings/ http://localhost:3000/listings/
```

Seems to be occurring when returning to a 404 page, so if the page returns 404 and you click on the same link, it will result to the above error.

Answer (score 2):

This issue can happen when you have a mismatch of pages routes, for example in my case I had the following structure:

```
pages
|-course
  |-[productId].js
  |-[courseId]
    |-summary.js
```

The mismatch was that the route could resolve with different variables (courseId, productId)

Changing it as follows fixed it:

```
pages
|-course
  |-[courseId]
    |-index.js
    |-summary.js
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be worth checking your `router.push`. We had the same issue and we put `router.asPath` to the `pathname`.

```
    router.push(
      {
        pathname: router.pathname, // not router.asPath
        query: { confirm: true },
      },
```

changing it to `router.pathname` solved.

Answer (score 0):

Got same issue :
`Error: Invariant: attempted to hard navigate to the same URL / http://localhost:3000/`

but ,

1. `npx kill-port 3000`
2. again run server by `npm run dev`

it worked for me

Comment: This is not a fix for the problem. It lays the groundwork for the error to reoccur in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Faced:**

In my case, I am trying to navigate to a page that is yet not created or not existed at all, so for the first refresh it works fine but if I try to navigate to the same URL using [next/link](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link) tag, it gives this error.

**Solution:**

A trick to resolve/workaround is by dealing this route as dynamic using **as** attribute of link tag  and let href attribute to be empty.

```js
<Link href="" as="/something">Go to something</Link>
```

Comment: Never use such tricks.